# Related List Items visible, but not clickable by Experience user

Tags: customer-community, digital-experience

We have a Digital Experience (aka Community) Support site for authenticated customers.

There is a custom layout associated with the external user's Profile `MyCompany Customer Community`.

The layout displays the Case Detail (selected fields) plus these related lists

- Emails
- Activity History (not using timeline here)
- Attachments
- Case Comments

Weirdly,

- the Email Subject is clickable and the experience user can drill down but ..
- the Activity History subject is visible but not clickable so no drill down possible

[image]

Seems to me that if the Experience user can see the activity history record `Subject`, they should be able to click on it?

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had me chasing down permissions rabbit holes and even engaging SFDC support.  Had I looked at this from the point of view of an HTML developer, I would have found the issue right away but when using Experiences with OOTB components, you are not oriented to think that way.

Turns out the site developer had added CSS Head markup to the site that did the following:

```
/* Disable hyperlinks except for links to case records from Case Number values, and EmailMessages */
a[data-refid="recordId"]:not([data-recordid^="500"]):not([data-recordid^="02s"]),
a[href^="mailto:"],
div.outputSubject a[data-refid="recordId"] {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    color: #333 !important;
}
```

So, since `ActvityHistory` records are either **Events** (prefix = `00U`) or **Tasks** (prefix = `00T`), the CSS made the links non-responsive to [pointer events](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp) (i.e., not clickable) with `pointer-events: none !important;` for all DOM elements matching the CSS selectors in the above snippet. Cases (prefix `500`) and EmailMessages (prefix = `02s`) were left untouched and were clickable.

So, the brute force solution was to change the CSS line:

from:

```
a[data-refid="recordId"]:not([data-recordid^="500"]):not([data-recordid^="02s"]),
```

to:

```
a[data-refid="recordId"]:not([data-recordid^="500"]):not([data-recordid^="02s"]):not([data-recordid^="00T"]):not([data-recordid^="00U"]),
```

*Left for another day is why Profile permissions can not be used to control all this.*